# Sort integer array using comparator interface and lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda

I am trying to sort an array of integers by implementing compare method of Comparator interface using lambda expression. I couldn't understand the error given by compiler. Please help.

I tried to execute the code below:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class MyClass{ 
    public static void main(String args[]) {

     int[] arr = {5,3,7,8,1,4,6,9};

    Arrays.sort(arr, (int o1, int o2) -> o1 - o2);

     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
}
```

Actual result:--

```
/MyClass.java:9: error: no suitable method found for sort(int[],(int o1, i[...] - o2)
    Arrays.sort(arr, (int o1, int o2) -> o1 - o2);
          ^
    method Arrays.<T#1>sort(T#1[],Comparator<? super T#1>) is not applicable
      (inference variable T#2 has incompatible bounds
        equality constraints: int
        upper bounds: Object)
    method Arrays.<T#3>sort(T#3[],int,int,Comparator<? super T#3>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#3
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
  where T#1,T#2,T#3 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1>sort(T#1[],Comparator<? super T#1>)
    T#2 extends Object declared in interface Comparator
    T#3 extends Object declared in method <T#3>sort(T#3[],int,int,Comparator<? super T#3>)
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error
```

Expected:-

Sorted array:

```
[1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Comment: Just remove the `, (int o1, int o2) -> o1 - o2` bit and you will get the expected result.

Comment: Also note that comparing `int`s by subtracting them is bad practice as the operation may overflow. Use `Integer.compare(i1, i2)` instead.

Answer (score 5):

There are no overrides of [`Arrays::sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html) that take an array of primitives and a lambda as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use an Integer[] array to sort with a Comparator. The sort method which takes an int[] array does not support passing a Comparator.

```
Integer[] arr = {5, 3, 7, 8, 1, 4, 6, 9};

Arrays.sort(arr, (Integer o1, Integer o2) -> o1 - o2);
```

Comment: `Arrays.sort(arr, (Integer o1, Integer o2) -> o1 - o2);` won't compile. use `Arrays.sort(arr, (o1, o2) -> o1 - o2);`

Comment: The code compiles fine for me. What error are you getting when you compile it? It compiles with and without the explicit parameter types in the lambda for me.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why, but I checked again just now and it can compile both in jdk 11 & open jdk 17.

Answer (score 1):

The `Arrays` class provide sorting for `primitives` so no `Comparator` is required.  That is why you can't specify one as an argument.  Of course, that also means you are limited to sorting in `ascending` order only.

To sort an int array in reverse or descending order, you can do the following:

```java
           // convert to stream
           arr = Arrays.stream(arr)

           // wrap it in an Integer object
          .boxed()

           // sort it with specified Comparator
          .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())

           // "unbox" it (convert from Integer to int)                            
          .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)

           // and return them in an array
          .toArray();
```

Or you can just start with an `Integer` array and do this.

```java
          Integer[] intArr = { 5, 2, 3, 7, 8, 1, 4, 6, 9
          };

          Arrays.sort(intArr,Comparator.reverseOrder());
```

Answer (score 0):

*Why should you use* `Arrays.sort()` *at all?*

`index = 0;  // declared as class variable`
`int[] arr = { 5, 3, 7, 8, 1, 4, 6, 9 };`

lambda reusing the old array:

```
IntStream.range( 0, arr.length ).boxed().map( i -> arr[i] )
  .sorted( (i1, i2) -> Integer.compare( i1, i2 ) ).forEach( i -> arr[index++] = i );  // arr == [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

…for natural sort order even boxing is unnecessary:

```
IntStream.range( 0, arr.length ).map( i -> arr[i] )
  .sorted().forEach( i -> arr[index++] = i );  // arr == [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Both solutions map the array contents to its corresponding index. This construct was choosen, because the resulting stream has a `sort()` function that takes a comparator as argument.
After sorting the values are written back to `arr` in the `forEach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

For the jdk15.
For primitive types, Arrays.sort gives you a variation of quicksort which is ascending order and that is fixed. You cannot fill in a comparator. If you want to sort the array in descending, you have to write ugly code to do  it. That's why I dislike java personally, and it makes things complex sometimes.

For reference types, Arrays.sort uses Timsort and you can fill in a comparator to customize it.